# Abstract class without defining in derived class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

*what is wrong with this code ?*

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void foo()=0;
};
class Derived : public Base{};

auto main() -> int {
    Base *b = new Derived;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what the compiler is telling you is wrong with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `Derived` is still abstract since the pure virtual function `Base::foo` hasn't been overridden.